# Elementary Mail unified inbox?

Tags: pantheon-mail

I have two exchange accounts set up in Mail, but I can only view one at a time.  Can I view both together in a unified inbox as in OS X Mail?  Thanks.

Comment: Agreed, it is useless for me until unified mail is available as I have many email boxes to watch.  I was hoping it was added in Juno but it is not :-(